# Is it possible to Autoscale other Kinds than Kind : Deployment in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, hpa

I want to use kind other than Deployment for Autoscaling in Kubernetes is it possible ? the reason I don't want to use kind:Deployment is the restart policy, as per as k8s documentation the only valid field for restart policy is "Always", and If put "Never" I am getting an error.

In my scenario I have a external monitoring UI which I use to shutdown the service if required, but now what happening is the pods are terminating and new pod are getting created. What should I do ? please note that I can not run it as kind:Pod as I want to auto-scale the services and Autoscaling of Kind:Pod is not valid !

Please share your suggestions and view on this ! thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HPA can be used with the following resources: `ReplicationController`, `Deployment`, `ReplicaSet` or `StatefulSet`. However HPA doesn't support scaling to 0.

There are some serverless frameworks that support scalability to zero in kubernetes such as [Knative](https://knative.dev/) and [Keda](https://keda.sh/).

Your use case sounds much simpler though, as you're looking to scale to zero based on a manual action. You can achieve this by setting the number of replicas of your deployment to 0.

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/{deploymentName}
```

And then if you want to re-activate the service then increase the replicas back again.

```
kubectl scale --replicas=1 deployment/{deploymentName}
```

Comment: thanks for your views . Also lets say there are  5 replicas running and I want to stop one externally ... in this case the deployment controller will again create that one replica after I stopped externally right ? is it possible to avoid this restarts ?

Comment: It depends, most likely yet, HorizontalPodAutoscaler will try to keep # of replicas to keep average metric utilization below configured threshold. You cannot avoid restarts if you delete a pod, but if you want to go from 5 to 4 replicas, just scale it to 4 replicas